# how to call atexit in a shared library?

Tags: c++, linux, dlopen, dlsym, atexit

In a shared library, a function func1() has atexit(terminate_global) and this shared library don't have '**attribute** ((constructor))' and '**attribute** ((destructor))'.

So, the program flow is like below:

1) Application loads shared lib using dlopen.

2) Applications calls func1() using dlsym.

3) func1() has atexit(terminate_global).

4) func1() returns.

5) Application calls dlclose to de-allocate the library.

In above steps I don't find the atexit() been called when the library was unloaded. So, what should be the correct way if the atexit() has to be called when we de-allocate the shared library? Should I export routines using the **attribute**((constructor)) and **attribute**((destructor)) function attributes so as atexit registered function can be called?

Comment: Application should call `atexit()`, not the library. Do not overcomplicate the things. If library needs cleanup, then it should just export some func, and app should call it at exit.

Comment: What is the use case that made you think of that? Please edit your question to motivate it a bit more...

Comment: The `atexit()` handler runs when the program itself closes, not when you unload the library/plugin. You need to add a deinitialize function to your library for that.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot. The code (or code flow) I am discussing is some legacy code which I just came across. I will try to use some de-initialize or '__attribute__((destructor))' to correct it. Will update back with the working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the `terminate_global` function passed to `atexit` is defined in the plugin. If `terminate_global` is a *global* function defined by the *main program* (linked with `-rdynamic` flag, to get its symbols accessing to plugins) then a plugin could call `atexit(terminate_global)`, but then I would provide some API function doing that.

I won't do that (calling `atexit(terminate_fun)` *inside* some plugin where `terminate_fun`  is a function defined by the plugin), unless you are sure that your application is *never* `dlclose`-ing the plugin.

If your application is somewhere calling `dlclose` -outside of some `atexit`-ing function- that `dlclose` is likely to `munmap` the `plugin.so` and when later `exit` is processing `atexit` it will crash (since the pointer to the function registered thru `atexit` is invalid and unmmapped)

You have to define who is in charge of `dlclose`-ing the plugin. If your application is explicitly doing that, you either could have some cleanup done by a `__attribute__((destructor))` C function (or the destructor of some static C++ data in the plugin), or *define and document a convention* telling e.g. that every plugin which has a function named `plugin_cleanup` (that you would get with `dlsym`) would have that cleanup function called appropriately.

You could otherwise define and document that plugins are not *explicitly* `dlclose`-d by your application (this is often OK, in particular if you offer some cleanup machinery). However, that may make `valgrind` unhappy.

Comment: According to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6455 glibc allows it